# Removing pairs from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose i have a list `a = ["1a", "1b", "2b", "3c", "2d", "1g", "3d", "3g"]` and I want to remove all pairs of elements that have the same coefficent/leading char in the element, such that it gives an answer like `["1g", "3g"]`.

How would I go about doing such a thing?

This is what I have reached till now, but it's a mess and isn't functioning quite well

```
def pairs(l):

    for x in range(len(l) -1,-1,-1):
        counter=0
        z=l[x][0]
        for f in range(len(l)-1,-1,-1):
            if z==(l[f][0]):
                counter+=1
        if counter%2==0:
            for i in range(x,x-1,-1):
                if z==(l[i][0]):
                   del (l[i])
        elif counter%2==1 :
            for i in range(x-1,x-2,-1):
                if z==(l[i][0]):
                    del (l[i])

    print(l)
```

Comment: I don't understand how you got your example answer. Why is "3g" in the answer when it shares a leading char with its neighbor "3d"?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why ["1g", "3g"] is your desired answer. Why not 1a or 1b or 3c?

Comment: @Kevin There are three elements with the first index "3", removing the pairs will leave only one element behind, which is "3g" in my example. Also bare in mind that the remaining element doesn't necesarily have to be "3g" it could be "3c" or "3d". Sorry if this wasn't clear enough

Comment: @A.Kot Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, yea if the elements occur an odd number of times, any element could be the remaining one, in my example i chose "1g" and "3g" but it could've been any other element with the same first index like "1a" and "1b" instead of "1g" and "3c" and "3d" instead of "3g".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = ["1a", "1b", "2b", "3c", "2d", "1g", "3d", "3g"]

coeffs = [a[0][0]] # collect coefficients
for i in a[1:]:
  if i[0] not in coeffs: coeffs.append(i[0])

s = [[x for x in a if x[0] == i] for i in coeffs] # groups according to coefficients
# s = [["1a", "1b", "1g"], ["2b", "2d"], ["3c", "3d", "3g"]]

solution = [i[-1] for i in s if len(i)%2]
# ['1g', '3g']
```

Comment: May you please further explain the fifth line of the code you provided. Thank you this was very helpful.

Comment: it will group the elements according to the coefficients. I updated a comment in my answer on how the grouped list will it look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the list elements based on the first character, then eliminate the pairs. For this, [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can come in handy:

```
>>> a = ["1a", "1b", "2b", "3c", "2d", "1g", "3d", "3g"]
>>> a.sort()
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> result = []
>>> for x, y in groupby(a, lambda x: x[0]):
...     y = list(y)
...     if len(y) % 2:
...         result.append(y[-1])
... 
>>> result
['1g', '3g']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def deleter(char,seq):
    if not seq or not isinstance(seq, list):
        return []
    else:
        if char==seq[0][0]:
            return function(char,seq[1:])
        else:
            return [seq[0]]+function(char,seq[1:])
```

I would solve it using a [*recursive*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Recursion) definition:

- **Base case**: if `seq`is empty there return an empty list
- **Check case**: if its element at index 0 is the char we hate then ignore it.
- **Solution**: `else return the first element in the list seq in a form of list and add to it the call of function itself`

**EDIT**:
I have a feeling that you are a new programmer if so, I just want to stress something about beauty and elegancy of recursive functions. It is an elegant mathematical way of solving problems. Your code will be pretty much easily readable by both new programmers, former programmers and mathematicians if they have any familiarity with *[proof by indcution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mathematical_induction)* in discrete mathematics. You basically follow the following pseudocode in most cases:

- **Base Case**: A condition to terminate your function
- **Return statement**: You return recursive a call of the function
  The way I visualize recursion is that you have a problem to solve, you assume you have created a function that solves the problem (base case) now you call the function to solve your problem(return a call of the function)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have to be overly complicated. Map the words by their leading characters but remove the existing item instead if the dictionary already has that key.

```
def pairs(a):

    result = {}
    for word in a:
        leading_char = word[0]
        if result.has_key(leading_char):
            del result[leading_char]
        else:
            result[leading_char] = word

    return result.values()

a = ["1a", "1b", "2b", "3c", "2d", "1g", "3d", "3g"]
print pairs(a)
```